# How nginx receives requests from client and forwards it to the actual server?

Tags: rhel, webserver, nginx, load-balancing

I have installed `nginx` on RHEL and now I need to configure it to forward the requests to the actual server in the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

My actual server is using a private IP address, will `nginx` forward requests to the private IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find a doc how to do it: http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Generally use HTTP proxy, from the example:

```
location /some/path/ {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com/link/;
}
```

It means that if you go to `yourserver.com/some/path/` the request will be forwaded to `http://www.example.com/link/`.

If you have an internal server,e.g. on `192.168.0.1` you can do:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1;
}
```

This way all that comes to `/` will be forwarded to your internal server.